# MySql SQL Query of Group by and Order by

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql. Which structure is :

```
id   sender   receiver        time              message
-------------------------------------------------------
1     23         34      2014-11-02 14:55:02      1
2     22         34      2014-11-02 16:55:02      2
3     21         35      2014-11-02 16:55:02      5
4     23         34      2014-11-02 16:55:02      2
5     22         35      2014-11-02 16:55:02      1
```

Now i need to make a query that will fetch the latest message of a particular receiver from a particular sender if the communication is more than one.Otherwise it give the single row .  Here i want to make a query with receiver id = 34 and it shouldgive me 4 th row and 2nd row. i.e.

```
2     22         34      2014-11-02 16:55:02      2
4     23         34      2014-11-02 16:55:02      2
```

Here i am not asking a particular number of  row from the db. This is a conversation db. And i want the conversation list of a user. And when there is more than one row for the same sender and receiver , then i want the latest conversation.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can get latest message time using group by and then use it in subquery to get all message details

```
 Select * from
 table1 T
 Join(
      Select sender ,max(time) as lastTime
      From table1
      Where receiver = 34
     Group by sender) T2
 On T.sender = T2.sender
 and T.time = T2.lastTime 
 And T.receiver = 34
```

Comment: Two things: You have a typo in your last line where you said `T1.lastTime` and you need to include the `WHERE receiver = 34` in the outer query also or else an extra row can be returned. Otherwise, it works. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/543b8/3)

Comment: What happened was that row 5 was also being returned, because it connected on sender = 22 and matching time, that's how I caught the receiver error.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve it and one way is to use left join then with the join condition group the data and finally the additional condition for further filter

```
select
m.* from messages m
left join messages m1 on m1.receiver = m.receiver
and m.id < m1.id
and m.sender = m1.sender
where m1.id is null
and m.receiver = 34;
```

Other way is to use `exists` as an alternative for `group by`

```
select m.* from messages m
where not exists
(
  select 1 from messages m1
  where
  m1.receiver = m.receiver
  and m.id < m1.id
  and m.sender = m1.sender
)
and m.receiver = 34;
```

**[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/509c7/12)**